# Unhealthy deployment

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, azure-machine-learning-service

I deploy a keras model (in python) to ML Azure. The deployment ends with the unhealthy state. What does that mean?
I deploy my model with this code :

```
image_config = ContainerImage.image_configuration(execution_script='script.py', 
                                                  runtime='python', 
                                                  conda_file='config_conda.yml')

   aciconfig = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores=1, 
                                               memory_gb=1, 
                                               description='')
   service = Webservice.deploy_from_model(workspace=ws,
                                       name=model_name,
                                       deployment_config=aciconfig,
                                       models=[model],
                                       image_config=image_config)
 
   service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
```

In the config_conda.yml file, what is the difference between the "pip" section and the "dependencies" section ?
I use the following packages in my script.py:

```
import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   import string

   #scikit-learn
   from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
   from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
   from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
   from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
   from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
   from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
   from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

   import nltk
   from nltk.corpus import stopwords
   from nltk.corpus import wordnet
   from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
   from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer

   # Word2vec
   import gensim

   # Keras  
   from tensorflow import keras
   from keras import metrics
   from keras.models import Sequential
   from keras.layers import Dense
   from keras.layers import Dropout
   from keras.layers import Embedding
   from keras.layers import LSTM
   from keras.layers import GlobalMaxPool1D
   from keras import utils
   from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
   from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

   import multiprocessing
```

Answer (score 1):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-and-where?tabs=azcli#understanding-service-state for understanding service state.

Also see [troubleshooting steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-troubleshoot-deployment)

"dependencies" will be installed with `conda install x` whereas things listed under "pip" will be installed with `pip install x`. Try to use the conda version whenever possible as it uses precompiled binaries that are less likely to cause issues.

Comment: Thanks Gopal for your answer :-)

Comment: How can the timeout be increased?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the endpoint ends up in Unhealthy state when there is something wrong with either the scoring script or the .yml file (script.py and config_conda.yml, in your case). You can use this command to see the logs and this normally tells you the issue:

```
print(service.get_logs())
```

Another debugging method is to try to deploy the service as a LocalService first:

```
myenv = Environment.from_conda_specification(name = "myenv", file_path = "config_conda.yml")

inference_config = InferenceConfig(entry_script = "script.py", environment = myenv)
deployment_config = LocalWebservice.deploy_configuration(port=6789)

local_service = Model.deploy(ws, "local-test", [model], inference_config, deployment_config)
local_service.wait_for_deployment(show_output = True)
```

In this way, all steps of the Docker container building process (incl. packages installation) are printed out. You can then delete the local service (local_service.delete()) when you're done.

By the way, you can also deploy ACI web services using Model.deploy instead of Webservice.deploy_from_model (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.webservice(class)?view=azure-ml-py). This is usually faster, as far as I've seen

Comment: Thanks Elena for your help. I'll try that.